# Audio cutting out in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

The Audio cuts out for around 2-5 seconds while playing high quality files.

The error I get in VLC is; `main warning: resetting master clock: coefficient too unstable: 604.491239`

I have tried turning off hardware encoding and setting Skip H.264 in-loop deblocking filter to all.

Comment: That's usually down to lack of free memory or high cpu load.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have around 16gb of ram, and it happens when VLC is just open.. Could this be because of slow ram?

Comment: Does it happen with other players, e.g., Audacity or MPC-HC? If not, the issue is in VLC, and if all have trouble, it might be hardware (e.g., RAM), drivers or OS.